# Travel by train from Trivandrum to Ahmedabad

Tags: trains, india, indian-railways

Is it safe to travel in train from Trivandrum to Ahmedabad in a Sleeper Class. Or do we need to opt for 2nd AC or 3rd AC ?

Comment: Safety in terms of what ?? Safety as in such is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Safety means , since its a sleeper class, most of the people can travel in these coach during day time (who has a sleeper ticket ), so will that ends in a really unsafe situation ?

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to travel in Sleeper class on all the routes. You may just want to be aware of your surroundings.

If you feel any issue at any point you can contact the following:
[@RailMinIndia](https://twitter.com/RailMinIndia)
[@sureshpprabhu](https://twitter.com/sureshpprabhu)